# npm failing (gyp error and install script error) during npm install homebridge on debian

Tags: node.js, npm, debian, node-gyp, npm-install

I am trying to install homebridge package on debian on my Dragonboard 410c  using 'npm install -g homebridge'. However, I keep running into the following error pasted below. I have already installed nodejs-legacy.

Is there a solution to this problem, or is there an alternative way to download and install the package ánd its dependencies without npm?

```
npm WARN excluding symbolic link utils/ncov -> lib/ncov.js
\

curve25519@1.1.0 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/homebridge/node_modules/hap-nodejs/node_modules/curve25519
node-gyp rebuild
(node) child_process: options.customFds option is deprecated. Use options.stdio instead.
make: Entering directory '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/homebridge/node_modules/hap-nodejs/node_modules/curve25519/build'
CXX(target) Release/obj.target/curve/node_curve.o
SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/curve.node
COPY Release/curve.node
make: Leaving directory '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/homebridge/node_modules/hap-nodejs/node_modules/curve25519/build'
npm WARN excluding symbolic link utils/ncov -> lib/ncov.js

bignum@0.11.0 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/homebridge/node_modules/hap-nodejs/node_modules/srp/node_modules/bignum
node-gyp configure build
(node) child_process: options.customFds option is deprecated. Use options.stdio instead.
gyp: Undefined variable openssl_config_path in binding.gyp
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: gyp failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/usr/share/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:344:16)
gyp ERR! stack at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
gyp ERR! stack at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.4.0-linaro-lt-qcom
gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/node-gyp" "configure" "build"
gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/homebridge/node_modules/hap-nodejs/node_modules/srp/node_modules/bignum
gyp ERR! node -v v4.2.2
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.12.2
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN This failure might be due to the use of legacy binary "node"
npm WARN For further explanations, please read
/usr/share/doc/nodejs/README.Debian

mdns@2.2.11 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/homebridge/node_modules/hap-nodejs/node_modules/mdns
node-gyp rebuild
path.js:424
var path = (i >= 0) ? arguments[i] : process.cwd();
^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, uv_cwd
at Error (native)
at Object.posix.resolve (path.js:424:50)
at Function.Module._resolveLookupPaths (module.js:249:17)
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:327:31)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:287:25)
at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
at require (module.js:385:17)
at Object. (/usr/share/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js:13:11)
at Module._compile (module.js:435:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:442:10)
npm ERR! bignum@0.11.0 install: node-gyp configure build
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the bignum@0.11.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the bignum package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR! node-gyp configure build
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR! npm owner ls bignum
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! System Linux 4.4.0-linaro-lt-qcom
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "homebridge"
npm ERR! cwd /home/linaro
npm ERR! node -v v4.2.2
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.21
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm WARN This failure might be due to the use of legacy binary "node"
npm WARN For further explanations, please read
/usr/share/doc/nodejs/README.Debian

ed25519@0.0.3 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/homebridge/node_modules/hap-nodejs/node_modules/ed25519
node-gyp rebuild
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend trying your commands from a different directory. I was trying to install a specific module in

> /Users/*my_username*/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.3/lib/node_modules/

and it was failing with a very similar error. I moved to

> /Users/*my_username*/.nvm/versions/

(accidentally) ran `npm install` and it's working now.

I also discovered `npm doctor` in this process, which may help you get to the bottom of your problem.